# Finding generators for an ideal consisting of the set of functions vanishing on a subset of Spec

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $U$ be the union of the $x,y,z$ axes in complex affine 3-space. The set of functions that vanish on $U$ is an ideal. Can we neatly express their generators?

There are a lot of similar such problems and I'm trying to get the flavor for how this is done.

Comment: What is the simplest possible function you can think of that vanishes on this space?  Will this function generate the ideal or do you need more?  Here's a hint: the ideal of functions vanishing on $U$ is the intersection of the ideal of functions vanishing on each of the axes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $U,V$ be two algebraic sets in $\mathbb{A}_\mathbb{C}^3$, with ideals $I(U)$ and $I(V)$. Then the ideal $I(U \cup V)$ is the set of functions vanishing on either $U$ or $V$ (or both). Then we see (show this!) that $I(U \cup V) = I(U) \cap I(V)$.

So in your case, the respective ideals are $(y,z), (x,z)$ and $(x,y)$, the ideals of the x,y and z-axis, respectively. The ideal of the union is the interesection of the ideals, so $I(U)=(yx,xz,yz)$. Make sure you can do the computation yourself.

Comment: Isn't the x-axis just $(x)$, since all functions that vanish on the x-axis have a factor of $x$?

Comment: @WouterZeldenthuis: No. Take the function $x$, for example. It does not vanish on (all of the) the x-axis. The x-axis are precisely the points with y- and z-coordinate zero.